# extend a class in typescript gives error

Tags: angular, typescript

I have two classes, one is a parent and the other one is a child, each class is in a separate file, 'base.ts' contains the parent class as follows:

```
base.ts
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
export class Base {
    constructor(public http?: Http) {}
    getJSON(url): Observable<any> { 
      return this.http.get(url)
        .map((res: Response) => res.json())
       .catch((error: any) => Observable.throw(error.json()))

    }

}
```

While the 'app.ts' file contains the child class as follows:

```
app.ts
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import { Base } from './base';
export class App extends Base {
   constructor(public http?: Http) {
    super(http);
  }
 run() {
   super.getJSON('./test-data.json') // or this.getJSON()
   .subscribe();
  }

}
```

Running the child class in a separate file

```
test.ts
class Test {
   constructor() {
     page = new App();
     page.run()
   }
}
```

The error I am getting in the Typescript is:

> Cannot read property 'get' of undefined

Comment: where is this error located? (file and line)

Comment: It point to the `base.ts` of `this.http.get()`

Comment: The problem is that you are creating `App` without passing an instance of `Http` so it is normal that `this.http` is not defined, hence the error!

Comment: should i have to add in `test.ts`

Comment: I think you should go back to reading the documentation of Angular: https://angular.io/guide/architecture and in particular the bit about dependency injection and how it relates to tests.

Comment: The problem may lie in angular `HTTP` module of injection. The compiler throws, it don't not know what is `get()` but not the function `getJSON()`. so need some alteration to work out.